# Property casting in linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm

I have class representing model for `ListViewItem` named `ItemViewModel`. `ItemViewModel` contains property Item of type object.

Next I have some class named `ListViewModel` with property `ItemCollection<ItemViewModel>`. Now I want to sort values in `ItemCollection` by some properties which are properties of Item property.

What is the best cast practice in this case?
I can do this:

```
 ItemCollection= ItemCollection.OrderBy((lvItem) => SongModel(lvItem.Item).Title).ToArray());
```

but i think there must be better solution.

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != IsSelected)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    object item;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return item;
        }
        set
        {
            item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

}

¨**Update:** I am sorry for misunderstanding. ItemCollection is only name of my collection. Actually in my case. ItemCollection is type of ObserverableCollection , so my ItemCollection does not have any property like ItemCollection.SortDescriptions. ItemCollection is bound to ListView, which is part of my View.

Comment: In the second paragraph you wrote `temCollection<ItemViewModel>` and in your code example above you are returning an array `ItemCollection= ItemCollection.OrderBy((lvItem) => SongModel(lvItem.Item).Title).ToArray());`. Nonetheless, the `ItemCollection<T>` was intended for exactly this kind of operations and stands valid. However as pointed below, using `ItemCollection<T>` inside ViewModel kind of violates MVVM pattern. There are other options, but none that's easily to use. You can use `CollectionViewSource`, which is bindable from XAML

Comment: You can check out my updated answer for an alternative, XAML only approach, assuming you don't need to determine sorting parameters at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are operating on the `ICollection<T>` interface of `ItemCollection<T>`. But `ItemCollection<T>` is capable of maintaining it's own state of the original data passed in.

What you want is to set `SortDescriptions` to one or more sorting criteria. For example

```
ItemCollection.SortDescriptions.Add(
    new SortDescription("Title", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

But keep in mind, your approach isn't fully MVVM compliant, as `ItemCollection<T>` and `CollectionView<T>` are part of the WPF framework, so they are part of the "View".

The view should be notified when the filter criteria changes and update the content appropriately.

**Update**: Also if you use an `ObservableCollection<T>` to bind to the list, the list will automatically be resorted/regrouped when a new item is added or removed.

**Update 2:**

The alternative, more MVVM compliant approach is to use the `CollectionViewSource` ([MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) which can be bound and used in XAML. This works fine if your sorting/grouping is static and you don't need to change it at runtime.

Example taken from [WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html).

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding}" x:Key="customerView">
           <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Country" />
           </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customerView}}" />
</Window>
```

The Source of the `CollectionViewSource` would be your observable collection.

If you need dynamic/runtime determination of sorting parameters, it may be a more work. You'd probably have to use attached behaviors or `IValueConverter` to accomplish it, but that's out of the scope of this answer.